# Absolute paths to Trigger.io assets?

Tags: trigger.io

We're building a Trigger app with Chaplin underneath. It would be nice, for development purposes, if we could use absolute paths to our assets, a la:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/_forge/stylesheets/app.css">
<script src="/_forge/javascripts/vendor.js"></script>
<script src="/_forge/javascripts/app.js"></script>
```

Is it possible to do this in Trigger?

Answer (score 3):

Unfortunately different platforms have different URLs on Trigger (due to them having their own features and limitations).

If you want to get absolute paths you can use the file module and do something along the lines of:

```
forge.file.getLocal("js/app.js", function (file) {
    forge.file.URL(file, function (url) {
        $('body').append('<script src="'+url+'"></script>');
    });
});
```

I'm not sure why an absolute path is useful though, I would recommend only using one html page (index.html) as navigating to a new page is slower on the phone than changing the dom using javascript. In which case all of your relative paths should always be the same.

Answer (score 1):

The easiest thing might be to detect the whether or not forge is present in your index.html and load the javascript accordingly:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  function addScript(src, callback) {
    var tag  = document.createElement('script');
    tag.type = 'text/javascript';
    tag.src = src;

    tag.onload = callback;

    document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0].appendChild(tag);
  }


  var vendor = "javascripts/vendor.js";
  var app    = "javascripts/app.js";

  if(window.forge === undefined) {
    vendor = "/"+vendor;
    app    = "/"+app;
  }

  addScript(vendor, function() {
    addScript(app, function() {
      require('initialize');
    });
  });
</script>
```